# nginx reverse proxy login not working

Tags: nginx, authentication, reverse-proxy

My nginx revers proxy server is like below. It shows the login page but i cannot login to it.

```
server {
        listen 80;

        listen 443 ssl;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;

        location / {
                proxy_pass "http://202.124.190.115:8080/derananews/";
        }
}
```

Comment: The error? You need to launch developer tools in chrome and watch the Network tab and see what error is occuring

Comment: I am having the same problem as you i use proxy_pass for whitelabel website and i can't login. Did you solve problem somehow?